# Bread Wallet on OS X

Tags: mac, breadwallet

How can I use my Bitcoin ID created in Bread Wallet on a OSX Desktop app. MultibitHD requires an Date stamp to "recover" passphrase. Is there a Mac app that works with Bread Wallet?

TIA,
Dave